# Finding RPMs for Install

Tags: rhel, yum

I'm trying to install later version of software for 2 RPM-based installations, but `yum` tells me that I already have the latest versions.

When looking to install software via `RPM`, what's the best way to find it?

Comment: What commands have you run thus far?

Comment: I searched for `OpenSSH 4.4` RPM via www.openssh.org, but I didn't find the RPM when looking through the mirrors' `/rpm` pages. My colleague has access to the `RHEL RPM Network`, so I'm not sure if I just need to look there.

Comment: If there is a package available, I would expect it to show up in the RHEL RPM Network prior to showing up in other places. Even this assumption is really dependent on the specific package. But in general that's why you pay for RHEL RPM Network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If yum tells you that the latest packages are already installed, then it is so. What makes you think there are newer packages available?

Comment: On `RHEL 5`, `yum` tells me that `OpenSSH 4.3` is the latest, however I can go to `OpenSSH`'s webpage and see newer versions of `OpenSSH`. I assume that the newer versions are also available via RPM.

Comment: @Kevin - That assumption isn't a good one. There isn't really any correlation to a new version being available on a particular software's site vs. an RPM being available.

Comment: My mistake. If there's a newer version, but the RPM isn't available, what's the standard way to proceed?

Comment: @slm, I said no _RPM_ is available.

Comment: Sorry @Vonbrand, my comment wasn't to you, to Kevin.

Comment: @Kevin, sit it out. The distribution might have sound reasons not to rush to the next version: Untested, subtle API changes, ...

Comment: @Kevin, Vonbrand is 100% correct. If it isn't available there are probably good reasons. Regression tests need to be performed, the new version might have bug fixes for other OSes, not RHEL, so they may be skipping it. There are really a whole slew of reasons. On such a core package such as OpenSSH, I would leave it up to the distro entirely.

Comment: @slm, the "enterprise" distributions just almost never change the base version of the software they ship (so APIs and so don't change) while backporting fixes very actively.

Comment: @vonbrand, yup, I see it in 100+ systems I support. You're advice is dead on to Kevin.

Comment: Thank you, vonbrand and slm. I'll wait for the official RPM upgrade

Comment: @Kevin, if you run an "enterprise" distribution, you won't see version updates. But the minor updates _will_ include whatever upstream changes are needed for security and other urgent reasons.

Comment: @vonbrand, using my `enterprise` distro, what can I do to install the minor updates? I don't understand `minor updates will include whatever upstream changes ...`